# sql query to include null

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and am not a programmer. Struggling with the following. Finally I give up and ask for your help.

```
SELECT `AccountNo`, -SUM(`Amount`) AS "Charged"
FROM `databasenamex`.`tablenamex`
WHERE (`Charge progress` BETWEEN 1 AND 2)
  OR IFNULL(`Charge progress` BETWEEN 1 AND 2, 0)
GROUP BY `AccountNo`;
```

This query returns only a two row-result corresponding to the summation of records where the stated condition is met. I thought the ... or ifnull()... section would include listing all other AnnountNo where the BETWEEN condition is not met. There are a total of 10 AccountNo selectable entries, and only two has other than zero sum. Btw, query result is the same without the ...or ifnull()... section.

The table has columns (among others) containing Amount, AccountNo and Charge progress.

What is the proper way to set up this query?

Comment: Could you please post some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Thank you all, @Mureinik, @Gordon @Linoff and Lennart for your interest in helping. I created a `testsql` database with two tables: tablesql and resultsql. The resultsql shows the query result I'm hoping for. Since I'm not familiar with this system I'll show the two tables in separate comments - sorry...

Comment: SELECT * FROM tablesql;
+-----------+--------+-----------------+
| AccountNo | Amount | Charge progress |
+-----------+--------+-----------------+
|         1 |      5 |            NULL |
|        23 |      6 |               3 |
|        23 |      7 |               2 |
|         3 |      8 |               1 |
|         3 |      9 |               2 |
|         3 |     10 |               2 |
|         3 |     11 |               3 |
|         3 |     12 |            NULL |
|         4 |     13 |            NULL |
|         4 |     14 |               3 |
+-----------+--------+-----------------+

Comment: mysql> SELECT * FROM resultquery;
+-----------+--------+
| AccountNo | Amount |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 |      0 |
|        23 |      7 |
|         3 |     27 |
|         4 |      0 |
+-----------+--------+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood your problem, but here's a try:

```
SELECT `AccountNo`, -SUM(`Amount`) AS "Charged"
FROM `databasenamex`.`tablenamex`
WHERE COALESCE(`Charge progress`, 1) BETWEEN 1 AND 2
GROUP BY `AccountNo`;
```

COALESCE is a function that returns it's leftmost not null value. so if `Charge progress` is null, 1 is the result which lies between 1 and 2.

EDIT: updated with table definition, some sample data and a modified query:

```
CREATE TABLE tablesql 
( ID int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, AccountNo tinyint(3) NOT NULL
, Amount smallint(5) DEFAULT NULL
, Charge progress tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL
,    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
,    UNIQUE KEY ID (ID)  -- redundant 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO tablesql 
VALUES (1,1,5,NULL),(2,23,6,3),(3,23,7,2),(4,3,8,1),(5,3,9,2),(6,3,10,2)
     , (7,3,11,3),(8,3,12,NULL),(9,4,13,NULL),(10,4,14,3);

select AccountNo, sum( case when "Charge progress" is null 
                            then 0 else amount end ) as amount 
from tablesql 
where COALESCE("Charge progress", 1) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 
group by AccountNo;

+-----------+--------+
| AccountNo | amount |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 |      0 |
|         3 |     27 |
|         4 |      0 |
|        23 |      7 |
+-----------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


select * from resultquery;
+-----------+--------+
| AccountNo | Amount |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 |      0 |
|        23 |      7 |
|         3 |     27 |
|         4 |      0 |
+-----------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Both methos of @Gordon Linoff and Lennart produces same result, but not what I expected - see my posted test database and expected result. Explanation: AccountNo 1 had no records between Charge progress 1 and 2, the only record has NULL charge progress. AccountNo 23 has one record with Amount 7 satisfying the criteria, etc. Therefore AccountNo 1 and 4 in query result show 0, and AccountNo 23 reults in 7, AccountNo 3 results in 8+9+10=27

Comment: Can you please either create an sqlfiddle, or provide create table and insert statements.

Comment: Sorry Lennart, I tried sqlfiddle but it complained about an error. Send me an email to jankom<at>aaahawk.com and I'll send you ascii text of the output of "SHOW CREATE TABLE tablesql", "SELECT * FROM tablesql;" and my awkward query posted as answering my own question that seems to accomplish what I wanted.

Comment: Just one more thing, when I intuitively hit <return> it posts my comment even though I only want to send a Cr+Lf. Since there is, next to this text box, an "Add Comment" button I did not expect <return> key to activate the posting. Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with the usage of this site, but it has been very helpful to me in the past, a rich collection of good answers by smart people - jankom

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE tablesql is fine since I then can create the table. However, SELECT * FROM tablesql will not give me insert statements that I can fill the table with, instead it requires me to create those statements myself. If you can provide insert statements that illustrates your problem I will gladly help, if not, I'm afraid that you will have to rely on someone else to help you.

Comment: Lennart, thanks again for your interest in this issue. Because of my unfamialirity of this web-comment interface I simply copy the mysqldump file here. I removed some comment lines for sake of brevity, and may have to break it up  into two comments due to the imposed character count limit. So here we go...

Comment: again, I hit return - sorry. -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: testsql
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

-- Table structure for table `resultquery`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `resultquery`;
CREATE TABLE `resultquery` (
  `AccountNo` tinyint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Amount` smallint(5) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: -- Dumping data for table `resultquery`

LOCK TABLES `resultquery` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `resultquery` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `resultquery` VALUES (1,0),(23,7),(3,27),(4,0);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `resultquery` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

Comment: -- Table structure for table `tablesql`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tablesql`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `tablesql` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AccountNo` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `Amount` smallint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Charge progress` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: -- Dumping data for table `tablesql`

LOCK TABLES `tablesql` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tablesql` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `tablesql` VALUES (1,1,5,NULL),(2,23,6,3),(3,23,7,2),(4,3,8,1),(5,3,9,2),(6,3,10,2),(7,3,11,3),(8,3,12,NULL),(9,4,13,NULL),(10,4,14,3);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tablesql` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

Comment: I hope this is it. There must be an easier way - sorry

Comment: I tried to re-read the thread but I'm not sure I understand, can you explain why accountno 1 gets amount 0, is it because "charge process" is null? Can you check whether this is correct: ` select AccountNo, sum( case when `Charge progress` is null then 0 else amount end ) as amount from tablesql where COALESCE(`Charge progress`, 1) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 group by AccountNo` I'll update the answer if it is

Comment: See below <br/> `mysql> select AccountNo, sum( case when "Charge progress" is null then 0 else amount end ) as amount from tablesql where COALESCE("Charge progress", 1) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 group by AccountNo;
Empty set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: Well, I tried formatting my comment with line break and code after reading Markdown Editing, but apparently I need to study it more. Anyway, after adjusting your statements by adding double quotes mysql processed it, but resulted in empty set as shown above. But to answer your question, YES, accountno gets 0 because Charge progress is NULL. The simple query would not include this result. This was the meaning of my original question: how do we include result of a query if some of the results in grouping would be null. My convoluted answer does produce the desired outcome.

Comment: The backticks vanishes in the comments, that's why you had to add doublequotes. Given your sample data the result of my query is exactly the same as that of resultquery, what data did you use when you ended up with an empty result?

Comment: I used data as shown above in the multiple part comments (INSERT INTO etc.). When I copied your statement (Ctr-C) mysql complained about space in Charge progress field name, so I had to enclose them with double quotes. You can see the copy of my screen above with the Empty set.

Comment: Again, I hit <Return> out of habit. Anyway, thank you, Lennart. I tried your statement in my actual database, and it worked as intended. I don't know, why it produced empty set. I'll find out, but that is besides the point. The point is that YOUR SUGGESTION IS THE CORRECT, ELEGANT SOLUTION TO MY QUESTION. Please, mark it as Answered, and thanks again for the learning experience - Janos

Comment: If not mistaken it is you who should mark it as answered ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you want:

```
SELECT `AccountNo`, -SUM(`Amount`) AS "Charged"
FROM `databasenamex`.`tablenamex`
WHERE `Charge progress` BETWEEN 1 AND 2 OR
      `Charge progress` IS NULL
GROUP BY `AccountNo`;
```

Your question, though, says that you want all of the rows.  Why are you using a `where` clause at all if you want all accounts?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an awkward, convoluted solution that seems to work

SELECT `AccountNo`, SUM( `Amount` ) AS Charged FROM (SELECT `AccountNo`, `Amount` AS AllCharges, IF(`Charge progress`<3,`Amount`,0) AS Amount FROM `testsql`.`tablesql` WHERE `AccountNo` between 3 and 4 or `AccountNo` = 23) AS xyz GROUP BY `AccountNo`;

See my test database in my comments.

There may be a simpler, more elegant solution, and am curious to see it.

Thanks again to those who have already responded to my help request

jankom